# is there an app button for the voice control on an iPhone 4?

Tags: applications, iphone, voice-dictation

is there any way besides holding the home button to get to the voice control on the iPhone 4 like an app button or anything?

Comment: A button in all apps or in one particular app?

Answer (score 2):

The (very) short answer is "No there isn't".

Answer (score 0):

If you bring the phone up to your ear, Siri should activate. However, the only button for interacting with Siri is the home button.

Comment: Not to mention that iPhone 4 doesn't officially have Siri.